How does the Warlock's invocation Gaze of Two Minds interact with the Unseen rule?
The warlock's invocation Gaze of Two Minds (GoTM) provides a fascinating ability to use another creature's senses and potentially cast spells as if the warlock is in their space.
However, there seems to be a lack of specificity regarding how the spells interact when they come from "the recipient" of the GoTM.
Gaze of Two Minds (emphasis mine)

You can use a Bonus Action to touch a willing creature and perceive through its senses until the end of your next turn. As long as the creature is on the same plane of existence as you, you can take a Bonus Action on subsequent turns to maintain this connection, extending the duration until the end of your next turn. The connection ends if you don’t maintain it in this way.
While perceiving through the other creature’s senses, you benefit from any special senses possessed by that creature, and you can cast spells as if you were in your space or the other creature’s space if the two of you are within 60 feet of each other.

I have presented a scenario in which the rules as written in the 2024 Players Handbook could leave players and DMs scratching their heads;
ADVANTAGE granted on a spell attack roll because the Warlock is not seen.  If a warlock has used GoTM on another character (we'll say a fighter for clarity later), then the warlock hid behind full cover (behind a closed door for example), then cast Eldritch Blast through the fighter using the GoTM feature, would the warlock make that attack with advantage?
On one hand, the answer could be "yes" because the warlock is an Unseen attacker.
Unseen Attacker as per 2024 Players Handbook pg 26 states in part:

When a creature can't see you, you have Advantage on attack rolls against it.

However, as the GoTM reads, the spells are cast as if you were in the space of the other creature (the fighter). It could be argued that the target saw the spell coming from the fighter, which could also be argued that the target was ready to defend itself against the fighter, thus negating Advantage.

Related: How does Gaze of Two Minds interact with Misty Step?

If the warlock is an unseen attacker, they get advantage
The creature you choose to perceive through with Gaze of Two Minds is neither the recipient of some ability, nor is it the attacker. You, the warlock, are the attacker.

you can cast spells as if you were in your space or the other creature’s space

The attack may come from the space occupied by the fighter, but what space an attack comes from is not the condition for Advantage from being an unseen attacker. The condition is that the target cannot see the attacker. So the warlock can get advantage on the attack, if the target cannot see them.
I think the headscratching for you comes from the fact that the target can see the fighter, can see its space, and thus can see the attack originating from there (if it is visible), so why would you get Advantage, which is intended for circumstances that make it easier for you to succeed? Why is it easier for you to hit when you yourself cannot be seen, all the while your attack can? The answer to this is up to you to come up with a satisfying reason - maybe because the fighter does something entirely different, which makes the sudden spell attack highly unexpected and surprising and thus harder to avoid? Or it is up to your DM, to overrule the rules here if they don't like them (or you, if you are the DM), but the rules are pretty straightforward.

RAW, all mechanics are determined as if the Warlock is the caster.
However, the 2024 Gaze of Two Minds does introduce a mechanic that breaks from most conventions in the game.

you can cast spells as if you were in ... the other creature’s space

It is no longer necessary for the Warlock to have A Clear Path to the Target of any spells, so long as the Gaze-Invoked-Fighter (in your example) does. This means that the Warlock can remain entirely hidden behind total cover while delivering deadly spells with advantage. On the other hand, it also means that the Gaze-Invoked-Fighter could be entirely Invisible and standing in a position geometrically opposite to the line from the Warlock to the target, and the spell would not get advantage. This may be dissatisfying for both players and DMs because it's unintuitive and breaks the immersive quality of role play.
Talk to your DM about what works best and feels balanced for everyone.
